# Print a file until certain characters found

Tags: perl

1. My script is fetching data from .txt file.
2. I need to print the data until I find "MSISDN1" in that file.

The code I have executed is:

```
open (SERVICE, "Service Req.txt") || die "Cannot open service req file $!\n";
my @serv=<SERVICE>;

open(LOG, ">>logfile.txt");

foreach $ser_req(@serv) {

#until ($ser_req =~ m/MSISDN1/g)
{
print $conn $ser_req;
print LOG $ser_req;
    print $ser_req;
}

close(LOG);
close (SERVICE) || die "Cannot close service req file $!\n";
```

The code does not run well, when the until condition is un-commented.

There is a very minute error in the code.
The until loop is not supposed to be applied.

Comment: `until` starts a loop.  You probably want `last if $ser_req =~ /MSISDN1/;` instead of the (`until`) loop.  You'll need to balance your braces `{ ... }` too.  You could sensibly close `SERVICE` immediately after slurping it into memory; release resources like files as quickly as you can.  If you decide not to slurp, then you replace the `foreach` with `while (<SERVICE>)` or something similar.

Comment: thank you for the wonderful piece of advice.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, nice deduction of what the problem is. Make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`until` starts a loop.  You probably want

```
last if $ser_req =~ /MSISDN1/;
```

instead of the (`until`) loop.  You'll need to balance your braces `{ ... }` too.

You could sensibly close `SERVICE` immediately after slurping the file into memory.  It's a good idea to release resources such as files as quickly as you can.  If you decide not to slurp the whole file (which would probably be better, especially if the marker text occurs near the beginning of big files), then you replace the `foreach` loop with `while (<SERVICE>)` or something similar.